# C# - Adjust height of TextBox on Windows Form using Mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

I need to implement a functionality (using .NET 2.0) for TextBox in Windows Forms, such that user should be able to adjust the height of the TextBox using mouse. User would click on the corner (or bottom) of the TextBox and drag, making the height of the TextBox more (or less).

Please provide some basic guideline on how this could be done.

Note: I have to use VS 2005 and .NET Framework V2.0

Thanks in Advance
-Mayur Jadhav

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question here

[Resizing control at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912397/resizing-control-at-runtime)

Create a custom control that inherits from textbox and add the resizing code to that and you should be good to go